# Will a new SSL certificate affect the existing one?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have an existing SSL certificate for a domain name.
(It's actually a wildcard/subdomain certificate).

I want to purchase a new SSL certificate for that same domain to extend the expiry. I want to do this well before the expiry to allow me time to propagate it to my various servers.
(Usual renew periods are 90 days before expiry, but I will be purchasing it 110 days before expiry).

Will purchase of this second certificate compromise, invalidate, or otherwise negatively affect the existing certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the two certificates can coexist and are totally different even if they are issued by the same authority, and have to same subject DN.